# how to execute a function after finishing the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework

i have this input :

```
<button type="button" title="test" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this); redirectToCart();">OK</button>
```

i want to execute the `redirectToCart()` after finishing the first one `productAddToCartForm.submit(this)` but without moving the first on, i mean the `productAddToCartForm.submit(this)` should stay in onclick button .

```
function redirectToCart()
{
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Comment: Add the `form` HTML and the `submit` function if you have any.

Comment: No, sorry i haven't it's just a button in fancy-box who calls the `productAddToCartForm.submit(this)` what i need is to redirect to another page after finishing the function

Comment: What is `productAddToCartForm`? Is it an HTMLForm? Also can you add the `submit()` function definition? Normal HTML Form submission results in a full page reload depending on the target of the form. You will have to [use AJAX for other behaviours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript)

Comment: Yes, it's an AJAX one i'll check this

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a few assumptions here, but the principle should work.

Primarily, I'm assuming that `productAddToCardForm.submit(this)` is triggering an AJAX request, either natively or using jQuery. In either case, you need to use **promises** to handle this.

There's a comprehensive guide [here](https://qntm.org/files/promise/promise.html), but the basics are as follows:

1. Return a Promise from your first function
2. Run your second function when the first function resolves successfully

That might look something like this:

```
function myFirstFunction(packet) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(productAddToCartForm.submit(packet))
  });

function doBothThings(packet) {
  myFirstFunction().then(redirectToCart())
};
```

I've put together a quick [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s007x3s8/25/) that demonstrates this better.

NB: This is about the simplest use case for Promises, but they are a really powerful tool. Full specs are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: doBothThings is not defined

Comment: there's a few errors in that code, sorry. Trying to fix it now

Answer (score 0):

It's easier and preferred to not use the inline events.

Just create a event listener and call both functions from there.

```
var myButton;
myButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    productAddToCartForm.submit(this);
    redirectToCart();
});
```

Comment: i put what in onclick button ?

Comment: Your solution calls the two functions successively, but what i need is to wait until the first one is finished and then execute the second one

Comment: This is not asynchronous. The functions get called and ran one at a time. I don't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: It might have been nice to tell me what the functions do. If you have a asynchronous request than obviously this will not work. By default functions run one by one (synchronously). What you are asking is what happens normally. Please show all the code!

Answer (score 0):

If productAddToCartForm is your javascript form element, you can do :

```
productAddToCartForm.onload = redirectToCart;
```